# Autohotkey v2 Loop issues

Tags: autohotkey

Hi im getting CRAZY trying to write this code and i would lvoe if someone could help me with this?
Basically i need a code that work in the Mythos application and it only works in that applicaiton, when the user clicks the letter F1 it should start running a loop and when he clicks F2 it stops the loop, also would love that it doesnt work outside the Mythos windows (minimized) but it keeps doing it outside, im getting CRAZY with this.

this is the code:

```
#HotIf WinActive("Mythos")

*n::
Loop {
     Send "{Click}" 
     Sleep 25
     Send "SC002" 
     Sleep 25
     Send "{Click}" 
     Sleep 25
}

*m::Suspend

#HotIf
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code uses `n` to start the loop and `m` to suspend the script, not `F1`/`F2`. Suspending a script doesn't terminate the loop, so once you restart it by pressing `m` again, the loop will continue from where it left off. Instead of using suspend you could create a toggle instead:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2
loopToggle := 0

#HotIf WinActive("Mythos")
*n:: {
    global loopToggle := 1
    While loopToggle {
        Send "{Click}" 
        Sleep 25
        Send "SC002" 
        Sleep 25
        Send "{Click}" 
        Sleep 25
    }
}

#HotIf loopToggle
*m::global loopToggle := 0
```

Notice that I also used a separate `#HotIf` for the second hotkey. This is because if your loop accidentally unfocuses Mythos, you migh have trouble stopping the loop (the `m` key would activate only when Mythos is active).